# Member "Push" not found... I tried to run my code the same way I did earlier with the Strings but this time with uints and it didn't work. New to Sol

Tags: solidity

I'm new to solidty so any new keyword is appreciated. I like the language so far, the syntax is close to Java and C#. I'm still a college student and the lack of info about solidity is a killer. I hope someone can help :/

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract MyTestContarct{
    Person[] public people;

    uint256 public peopleCount;

    struct Person {
        string _firstName;
        string _lastName; 
    }

    function addPerson(string memory _firstName, string memory _lastName) public{   
    people.push(Person(_firstName, _lastName));
    peopleCount +=1;
        
    }

    uint[] IntArrayTest;

    uint256 public elementsCounter;

    struct Numbers{
        uint _number;
    }
    

    function addElements(uint _number) public{
        IntArrayTest.push(Numbers(_number));
        elementsCounter +=1;

    } //It worked with string, why not with uint?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`IntArrayTest` is of type `uint[]` (array of unsigned integers), so you can only push `uint` items to this array.

However `Numbers(_number)` is not an `uint` - its type is `Numbers`.

You can create a `Numbers` variable in memory, and then pass its `_number` member (which has the `uint` type) to the `IntArrayTest` array.

```
uint[] IntArrayTest;

function addElements(uint _number) public{
    Numbers memory numbers = Numbers(_number);
    IntArrayTest.push(numbers._number);
    elementsCounter +=1;
}
```

Or if you want to pass the `Numbers` type to an array, you'll need to delcare an array of this type.

```
struct Numbers{
    uint _number;
}

Numbers[] NumbersArrayTest;

function addElements(uint _number) public{
    NumbersArrayTest.push(Numbers(_number));
    elementsCounter +=1;
}
```